# Margins in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to display dotted margin in table layout in my application. 
Is it possible or not ?
If yes then how..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Then try this

```
<TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1" android:background="@drawable/dot"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Your text"></TextView>

</TableRow>
```

I have set the background dotted image in the table row

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you need to give margin of 10 dip in your tablelayout. So instead of giving margin of 10 dip, you can use an image having dots of your choice with the calculated size using the below formula:

pixels = dps * (density / 160)

Comment: I am new to android. I don't know how to implement this.
Can you have an example related to it or any good tutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TableLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <TableRow android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent">
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/dot"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ImageView>
        <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Your text"></TextView>
        <ImageView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:src="@drawable/dot"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"></ImageView>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Between where you have used this formula => pixels = dps * (density / 160) ?

Comment: Well that was not used by me, I have applied the look around and better solution with that... anyways does that fulfills your requirement??

Comment: Ok. But its not fulfilling my requirement. I wanted to separate table rows by dotted lines. But as we know that android does not provide direct facility for drawing borders in table. So i used margin to separate those rows. I don't want default line style of margin. I want to display dotted lines there.

Comment: Hey i got it working. But its not good as for displaying n dots i hav to take n ImageViews..So how to overcome this ?
Is is possible by coding ?

Comment: try setting the image as drawable background